# Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: | Error when trying to update data in database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to make a poll where the user is voting through a PHP page sending data to a database where I store the values of the poll results.

I'm also trying to make it not possible to vote with the same account more than once. In this area, I've hit a roadblock. When I take the `ID` which in the code is `$userid` which is collected from a query and then passed to the `vote.php` in a `$_SESSION` it says that

> Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 3.

It's calling my variable DOUBLE value?

Code of Login.php :

```
$sqlID = "SELECT ID FROM Users WHERE Konto = '$user'";
        $checkID = $connection->query($sqlID);

        while ($row = $checkID->fetch_assoc()) {
            $setID = $row['ID']."<br>";
        }


        $_SESSION['sess_id'] = $setID;
        $_SESSION['inloggning'] = TRUE; // Ger inloggning en boolean som används senare.
```

Code of Vote.php :

```
$userid = $_SESSION['sess_id'];

$voteValidate = "SELECT has_voted FROM Users WHERE ID = '$userid'";
$voteValidationResult = $connection->query($voteValidate);

while ($row = $voteValidationResult->fetch_assoc()) {
    $checkVoted = $row['has_voted']."<br>";
}

if ($_SESSION['inloggning'] != TRUE || $checkVoted != 0) { // Tar variabler från login.php och kontrollerar dem, om de inte är sanna så skickas man tillbaka.
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Du är antingen inte inloggad eller så har du redan röstat.');</script>";
    // header("Location: skyddad_sida.php"); // Skickar tillbaka en användare om de har kommit till skyddad_sida.php utan att gå igenom login.php.
    exit;
}
if (isset($_POST["voteOriginal"])) {
    $voteQuery = "UPDATE polls_choices SET poll_vote_amount = poll_vote_amount + 1 WHERE poll_choice_name = 'Original'";
    $voteExecute = $connection->query($voteQuery); // Utför förfrågan i databas.
    $preventVote = "UPDATE users SET has_voted = 1 WHERE ID = '$userid'";
    if ($connection->query($preventVote) === TRUE) { // Queryar databasen och kontrollerar att det fungerade.
        echo "<strong><font color ='green'>Bra.</font></strong>";
      } else { // Annars blir det en error.
        echo "Error: " . $preventVote . "<br>" . $connection->error . "$userid";
      }
```

Comment: Have you checked your userid value as it looks as though you set it to `$row['ID']."<br>";` in the first script - not sure why you have the `<br>` tag as well.

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries